# Validation Rule Newb - Prevent Account Owner Edits when Check box = true (except admin role)

Tags: validation-rule

I'm very new to validation rules but at first glance the potential looks amazing!

I'm trying to set up a validation rule on the Account owner field so that it cannot be edited by any users except role = Administrator when a completely different account field (checkbox, called Master List 2015) is true.

I'd appreciate any help to point me in the right direction!

Thanks,
Kathy

Comment: Side note, since you're new to the group, as a rule this group doesn't 'do work' for people.  We like to help/guide users after making an attempt, so more detail in the future regarding what you've tried, including a paste of the code/formula you wrote will get you better response.  Best of luck, and welcome!

Comment: Fair enough - it seemed silly to share code that I knew wasn't going to work, but if it makes the community feel more validated I can see the point. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have an issue when the actual owner tries to change the owner, since depending on your object and profile settings, he/she may still be able to make the change.  But if the person making the change is not the record owner, THIS should work:

```
and(ischanged( OwnerId ), Master_List_2015__c =true, $User.ProfileId <> 'SFID of the Admin Profile')
```

Comment: HomerJ - I think you a) want to use $Profile.name <> 'AdminProfileName' (better self-documenting) and b) the `= true` is unnecessary as `master_list_2015__c` is a boolean

Comment: Agreed on name v. Id, but I would add that while redundant, a beginning admin reading the rule might not 'get it' unless the TRUE is there. But the formula would work without, as you suggested.

Comment: To confirm I understand correctly: using "Master_List_2015_c" alone is assumed to mean true when using a true/false check box?

I got it working with the Profile.Name <> Admin approach. I don't see why that might still allow the owner to make the change - do you mind sharing more info (or an example) about that?

Thanks all!

Comment: I see your point re beginning admin on checkbox fields - which is why I almost always name mine like sfdc does - `Is _xxx__c` or `Has_yyy__c`. In OP example, it would be `is_on_2015_master_list__c`